# Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, spring, routes, frontend, angular-httpclient

I am practicing some app creation with spring boot and angular but keep getting this error when I try to link angular to spring.

"Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ErrorClass[]>'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'ErrorClass[]': length, pop, pus"

Class:

```
export class ErrorClass{
id: number;
title: string;
description: string;
dateOfCreation: string;
```

}

Problem area :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ErrorClass } from '../models/ErrorModel';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorServiceService {


  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/errors";
  constructor(private client: HttpClient) { }


 public getErrorList(): Observable<ErrorClass[]>{
   return this.client.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @SilentSlippers, Please add the code snippet instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getErrorList` function returns the Observable of `ErrorClass` Array. The HttpClient.get() method parses the JSON server response into the anonymous type. It doesn't know what the shape of that returned response is.

To supress the type error at compile time, return the `typed` response from `http get` request.

```
public getErrorList(): Observable<ErrorClass[]> {
  return this.client.get<ErrorClass[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
}
```

**Requesting a typed response**

> Structure your HttpClient request to declare the type of the response
> object, to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.
> Specifying the response type acts as a type assertion at compile time.
>
> Specifying the response type is a declaration to TypeScript that it
> should treat your response as being of the given type. This is a
> build-time check and doesn't guarantee that the server actually
> responds with an object of this type. It is up to the server to ensure
> that the type specified by the server API is returned.

See - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/aio/content/guide/http.md

Comment: Can we change the anonymous type from other line? I am doing test, and i cant change the original code.